# Recover deleted text from draft post

Tags: draft

I was writing a post, went to copy it and accidentally pressed paste, this deleted my entire text, about 900 words with and replaced it with whatever I had previously copied. Because it's a draft it won't let me see revisions. Is there any way I can recover this?

Comment: if it was not saved then it is gone, the best thing you can do is to use undo to undo the paste, but if you've already closed the tab then it is gone forever. Note though that this stack is for code questions, if you need user support you should ask on the wp .org support forums